# Any (fast) way to check a function is constant/almost constant?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I encounter this problem when I want to adopt lazy object pattern, and at some point when some function (one of user inputs) might be constant function. I want to check if the function is constant before feeding it into the loop.

My current solution is a somewhat ugly workaround using `np.allclose`:

```py
def is_constant(func, arr):
    return np.allclose(fun(arr), func(arr[0]))
```

you can also use things like `np.maximum == np.minimum` kinds of stuff, which can work slightly faster.

But I was wondering if there is any fast way to do that? As the above was still calculate the function over a somewhat large array already.

Comment: Do you mean a function in a mathematical sense, or programming? What are your criteria for "almost" constant?

Comment: @BartoszKP I guess for a pure math sense We'll have to involve `sympy` for functions of form `x/x` a pure check of parameters (if any) will not be helpful. In such case I mean programming. Like `np.allclose` has parameter of `atol` (tolerance level), I think it's more sensible to allow such form of tolerance, especially when floating computation cannot be always accurate. I would say in general `1e-08` would be good enough

Comment: The floating point tolerance is minor problem. Probing a function for every possible argument is impractical. Without verifying every possible argument you will never no if there isn't some input producing a different value, then the ones you've verified.

Comment: I'm confused at how one might analyze an arbitrary function, faster than checking each of its empirical values once.  Can you elaborate what manner of solution you have in mind?  Your `allclose` solution is already **O(n)** with a very low constant.

Comment: @BartoszKP Say if the function is Hölder-continuous and bounded (or any other regularity conditions that's in your mind), I would be too worried about the bumpy part of the function as long as my test-grid is fine enough(say `1e-05`) . Moreover, keep in mind what I want to verify is just almost-constant, so there is no need to check all occurrences.

Comment: @Prune I am just curious if there is any elegant/smart way to work on this. For example if the function is nicely inputed `func = lambda x: 0.5`, then a `func([1,2]).size == 1` already do the trick, which is `O(1)`. After all, I did not know much about inner structure of numpy and was hoping if someone can enlighten me

Comment: What exactly does `func([1,2])` do? It appears that you're just checking the output of `func` on each value in some set, but unless that set is the domain of your function, you haven't learned *anything* about whether the function is constant or not, only that it is constant for a particular subset of its domain.

Comment: @chepner Sorry for not making it clear. Since non-constant 1d-function will automatically broadcast if applying to numpy arrays, I sort of exploit it that, and if the function is written of the form I used above, `func(arr)` will only give one value. So checking output size would suffice

Comment: @Wunderbar That's why I asked what are your criteria for "almost". I'm not sure how `func([1,2]).size == 1`is relevant here - your are checking the dimensions of the resulting vector here - what's that got to do with function being constant or not?

Comment: If you expect continuity, you could do a fast preliminary test by comparing subsamples from both signals. However the worst case will happen for equal signals. If you know the highest frequency the continuous signal has then you only need a fmax*2 samples to guarantee equality.